# Proving that disjoint affine subspaces (with one a hyperplane) of $\mathbb{R}^k$ 'are parallel when translating to zero'

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove this seemingly straight forward statement:

> Let $S,T \leq \mathbb{R}^k$ be subspaces with $S$ a hyperplane and $p,q \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Then, if $S+p$ and $T + q$ are disjoint, necessarily $T \subseteq S$.

Nevertheless I have been going in circles without much success: I intuitively see this happening when $k \leq 3$, but I haven't managed to translate the intuition into a proof. Any hints?

Comment: If you mean subvectorspace by subspace, two subspaces are never disjoint. So I guess you mean something else.

Comment: @James note that the subspaces are translated. For example, the line $\langle (1,1,0) \rangle$ is disjoint with $\langle (1,1,0) (1,-1,0) \rangle + (0,0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the projection $\pi : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k/S$. What does the disjoint condition + S being a hyperplane tell you about the image of T under $\pi$?

> Let $\pi : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k/S$ be the projection onto the quotient by $S$. Here $S+p$ and $T+q$ being disjoint means that if $t \in T$ then $\pi(t + q) \neq \pi(p)$. In other words, $\pi(t) \neq \pi(p) - \pi(q)$ for any $t \in T$. But $\pi[T]$ is a subspace of the one-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^k / S$ so is either $0$ or all of $\mathbb{R}^k / S$. Thus $T \subseteq S$.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood correctly: by the contrareciprocal if $T \not \subseteq S$, then necessarily $\pi(T) = \mathbb{R}^k/S$ by a dimension argument and in particular there should exist $t \in T$ with $\pi(t) = \pi(p-q)$ which implies that $(S+p) \cap (T+q)$ is nonempty. Right?

Comment: @GuidoA. That seems right to me! Also, it's contrapositive instead of "contrareciprocal" in English.

Comment: Great! And yeah, I 'know' that the correct word is 'contrapositive' but for some reason I keep making this mistake. I can't edit it but I appreciate the comment nonetheless. As for the answer, I found the argument really clear and to the point. Thanks a lot!